# 404 with Codeigniter 3 on LAMP, but however working on MAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, router

I started a new project on CI3.
I developed it on my MB with MAMP. Everything works fine !

This afternoon I tried to publish the code on my VM serveur ( Ubuntu 18.04, php 7.2.19 ).
The welcome page works good, but impossible to use a routes.

```
localhost/index.php -> good
localhost/index.php/push/ -> 404 ( still working on MAMP )
```

I tried to use an .htacces, create a route in router.php file, ....

/application/controllers/api.php :

```
class Push extends REST_Controller{


public function _construct(){
....
}


public function index_post(...){
...
}

}
```

always a 404 NOT FOUND on LAMP only

Comment: did you added htaccess in root folder? check in php your mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Mac OS is case insensitive, but the Linux OS is case sensitive. CodeIgniter requires that file and class names match exactly and that they have an uppercase first character in the name with all other characters being lowercase. On a case insensitive system you can get away with ignoring that convention, but on a case sensitive system you cannot.

BTW, it is Controllers, Models, and Libraries that are case sensitive. In essence, any file that defines a PHP class.